# Is there a way to group by intervals of 15 min in DuckDB?

Tags: sql, business-intelligence, olap, duckdb

I made a table with

```
create table counter (
  createdat TIMESTAMP,
  tickets INT, 
  id VARCHAR
)
```

and I would like to group the rows by intervals of 15 min, so I am trying to do it with:

```
SELECT
  SUM(tickets) AS total,
  extract(year from createdat),
  extract(month from createdat),
  extract(day from createdat),
  extract(hour from createdat)
from counter
where id = ?
group by
  extract(year from createdat),
  extract(month from createdat),
  extract(day from createdat),
  extract(hour from createdat)
```

With this query I am getting only by hour. However I cant modify it to minutes.

How would be the query to group by intervals of 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an expression for the quarter hour:

```
(extract(minute from createdat) / 15)::integer
```

to your columns:

```
select
  sum(tickets) AS total,
  extract(year from createdat),
  extract(month from createdat),
  extract(day from createdat),
  extract(hour from createdat),
  (extract(minute from createdat) / 15)::integer
from counter
where id = ?
group by
  extract(year from createdat),
  extract(month from createdat),
  extract(day from createdat),
  extract(hour from createdat),
  (extract(minute from createdat) / 15)::integer
```

Casting to `integer` truncates the fractional part of the division result.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! is this the better query to get intervals by 15 mins or is there other queries with better performance?

Comment: @jaox this is the only way AFAIK and it will perform quite well - simple arithmetic operations like this are pretty fast

Answer (score 4):

An easier way is to use `time_bucket`

Example:

```
SELECT time_bucket(INTERVAL '15m', createdat) AS bucket, SUM(tickets)
FROM counter
GROUP BY bucket
ORDER BY bucket;
```

Docs: https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/timestamp.html